# Ignore exceptions in python with FTP

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, ftp

I am trying to write a quick little program that will parse through a CSV file pull usernames and passwords and test login to a FTP to create a directory and delete it with those usernames and passwords. I have written a try catch so it can output any errors I get so that I can review which FTP logins may need tweaking. The problem is when I run it, it will stall if any of the logins are broken instead of proceeding. I have tried using `pass` and `finally` after my try but it won't return to the loop. Any help is appreciated.

```
import csv
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
with open ('Filename.csv') as csvfile:  
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    lineCount = 0
    rowCount = 0
    for row in readCSV:
        username = row[rowCount]
        passwordFTP = row[rowCount+1]
        print (username)
        ftp = FTP('ftp.org') #place the FTP address here 
        ftp.set_debuglevel(2) #this is set to highest debug level 
        try: 
            ftp.login(user='usernameGoesHere', passwd='passwordGoesHere', acct='')
        except ftplib.all_errors as e:
            errorcode_string = str(e).split(None, 1)[0]
            pass
        finally: 
            ftp.cwd('/TestDir')
            ftp.mkd('testDir')
            ftp.rmd('testDir')
            ftp.quit()
            pass
```

Comment: Show us some evidence - Log file from ftplib + Add some debug output to your code and shows us what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no pint in putting the code in `finally`. Despite the fact that you have put a `pass` statement, it has no role in this code. On getting an error on login the program will log the error and still try to make a folder for the given connection.

Instead move the `cwd`, `mkd` and other methods to the `try` block. If an error is thrown there, the `except` will catch it and stop the execution.

There is absolutely no need to put `pass` statements anywhere in the `try`. The only thing that can still remain in the `finally` block is `ftp.quit()` so it cleans up, closing the connection if one of the operations fails, but on the other hand what will happen if login is not successful?

Do something like:

```py
with FTP('ftp.org') as ftp
    try: 
        ftp.login(user='usernameGoesHere', passwd='passwordGoesHere', acct='')
        ftp.cwd('/TestDir')
        ftp.mkd('testDir')
        ftp.rmd('testDir')
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        errorcode_string = str(e).split(None, 1)[0]
```

Using context manager (the `with` statement) will help you quitting manually.

Comment: This solved it, should have been obvious that it won't be able to try anything else if the login fails. Thank you!